# compressed vs uncompressed feasibility question?

Tags: quality, vimeo

I have multiple videos uncompressed. I uploaded them a while ago to vimeo. I lost the original files. However, I found the original files stored in vimeo under the download button below the 1080p version. I realized that the 1080p WAS 100MB in size, whereas the 1080p original was 1.96GB.

In term of storage saving the 100mb IS IDEAL, however will i lose quality? I still cannot grasp the differences btw these two version. if possible would someone explain the differences? 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine, a file that is compressed from 1.96gb to 100mb has lost a lot of information. The question is what you need to do with this film now. If you want to make a version to be shown in cinemas, that's not going to work well since you probably will see compression artifacts etc on a big screen. If you need to create a Sd DVD from it, probably that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any video that you upload to sites like Youtube or Vimeo is recompressed in order to standardize the video files they stream to viewers. That version looks to be what you're downloading, but it should be the original upload. Double-check that.

The quality difference of the smaller file, for viewing purposes, should be fine since the compression presets these sites apply is meant to keep quality acceptable while lowering file size. This generally holds unless the footage consists of shots with a lot of fine detail.

The only way to judge whether the smaller file is acceptable is to download and view it.